# How can I push an object to a nested array of objects in mongoDB and expressjs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have the following Board object:

```
{
    "boardMembers": [
        "5f636a5c0d6fa84be48cc19d"
    ],
    "boardLists": [
        {
            "cards": [],
            "_id": "5f6387e077beba2e3c15d15a",
            "title": "list one",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ],
    "_id": "5f63877177beba2e3c15d159",
    "boardName": "board1",
    "boardPassword": "123456",
    "boardCreator": "5f636a5c0d6fa84be48cc19d",
    "g_createdAt": "2020-09-17T15:57:37.616Z",
    "__v": 2
}
```

as you can see there is a "boardLists" array, I want to make a post request that post a card to a list inside that array with specific ID.

that my code:

```
router.post("/add-task/:id", auth, boardAuth, async (req, res) => {
  const listId = req.params.id;

  try {
    const board = await Board.findOne({ _id: req.board._id });
    if (!board) return res.status(404).send("no such board");

    const list = await List.findOne({ _id: listId });
    if (!list) return res.status(404).send("List not found");

    const task = new Task({
      text: req.body.text,
    });

    Board.updateOne(
      { _id: req.board._id, "boardLists._id": listId },
      { $push: { "boardLists.$.cards": task } }
    );

    await board.save();
    res.send(board);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Now the problem is when I make the request call in postman its does the push inside the specific list that i want but its not saving the push inside the parent board object: when do a get request to that object i get an empty cards array.
like that:

```
{
    "boardMembers": [
        "5f636a5c0d6fa84be48cc19d"
    ],
    "boardLists": [
        {
            "cards": [],
            "_id": "5f6387e077beba2e3c15d15a",
            "title": "list one",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ],
    "_id": "5f63877177beba2e3c15d159",
    "boardName": "board1",
    "boardPassword": "123456",
    "boardCreator": "5f636a5c0d6fa84be48cc19d",
    "g_createdAt": "2020-09-17T15:57:37.616Z",
    "__v": 2
}
```

Why its not saving the push in the board object?

Comment: why all comments deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongoose is weird. You need to mark the field as modified, otherwise the changes won't be saved. Try this :

```
board.markModified("boardLists");
await board.save();
```